# RPC performance in large network

Tags: sockets, rpc

I have a large network, supposed to manage around 8000 nodes (the requirement is for client server based filesystem)
. Which of the following implementation is better - "RPC (ONC RPC) using TCP" or "direct socket using TCP"?

Comparison points should be:
1. memory
2. bandwith issues
3. Performance
4. Any disadvantage while using RPC

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is a little more memory, bandwidth, and performance overhead when using RPC.  However, RPC can greatly simplify your logic.